# How to pass an information from jsp page and retrieve it later using jsp in Struts2

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, struts2

I have created one Struts2 application in that application first you need to create an account by creating your username, password, phone, address and amount that you are going to credit to your newly created account. I am able to get this process done so now I can see values in database. But when I want to check my balance, I need to enter username and password and account number, when I enter all these 3 information, I should be able to get that one particular row from the database. I have done this in servlets but I know it can be done easily through Struts2.

So, please tell me how can I do this in Struts2. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Read about Struts controller and how to use the model.

Comment: Too many words and no code. If you can save to database, then you can retrieve info as well. With what exactly are you having problems?

Comment: I am asking if i am using struts2, do I have to write any database related code in jsp?

Comment: @user2424732 It is not about Struts 2 ,it is about the best MVC design approach you need to follow when developing web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
method 1 : set as request Attribute
```

set the attribute in current JSP by :

```
request.setAttribute(name, value);
```

And now get the value in next JSP by :

```
request.getAttribute(name)

method 2 : set as session Attribute
```

for setting the value in session

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
```

for getting the value from session

```
session.setAttribute("theName", name);

method 3 : store in hidden filed and keep passing
```

setting values in hidden field is as simple as passing values in text field
only create the text field hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name="something" value="something"/>
```

Comment: thanks  Hussain but in the above 3 method which one is best suited for struts2?

Comment: in my experience session is the best option unless you are storing files in the session which is affects application performance

Comment: @user2424732 : hidden field should be avoided for security reasons and session should be preferred

Comment: okay..thanks. one more doubt, if i am retrieving values, I need to use database related code in jsp page, do I have to use it even in struts2?

Comment: for retrieving values from request or session , you cant use database related codes , and if you are talking about retrieving normal values from data base in strut application then i would suggest , check sql tags in jsp and struts

Comment: i just want to store accontno, username, password, phone number etc. so..wat you suggest me now.

Comment: i would suggest you follow the struts flow , create a bean and store the values in the bean